# ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints - while installing python using APK

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    python \
    py-pip
RUN pip install awscli

# remaining code...
```

But when I build this, I get the following logs with an error:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache  ca-certificates     curl    python  py-pip

fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:

  python (missing):

    required by: world[python]

The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache  ca-certificates     curl    python  py-pip' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have found some questions which described the same error but the solution doesn't help me.

Do I need to mention the **python** version? I would really like to use to install latest version only.

Comment: `py-pip` has a dependency on current Python (`python3`) so you don't need to explicitly include `python`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. I will remove the **python** in **apk add** command and give it a try.

Comment: It resolved my problem. Thanks @DavidMaze